# Read text file into list based on specific criterion

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a text file with the following content:

```
str1 str2 str3 str4
0        1    12     34
0        2      4     6
0        3     5      22
0       56    2      18
0         3    99    12    
0         8    5       7      
1       66    78    9
```

I want to read the above text file into a list such that program starts reading from the row where first column has a value greater than zero.

How do I do it in Python 3.5?

I tried genfromtxt() but i can only skip fixed number of lines from top. Since I will be reading different files i need something else.

Comment: You could read all the rows and then filter out 4 numbers at a time if the first one < 0

Comment: `if float(split(f.readline())[0]) != 0:` would be one way, although be ready to catch exceptions for the headers.

Comment: What is `0.3.`?

Comment: I think you might be able to do it quite cleanly with pandas as well.

Comment: Can you show what you actually did?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way with `csv` module.

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""\
str1 str2 str3 str4
0        1    12     34
0        2      4     6
0        3     5      22
0       56    2      18
0         3    99    12    
0         8    5       7      
1       66    78    9
2       50    45    4
""")

res = []

# replace mystr with open('file.csv', 'r')
with mystr as f:
    reader = csv.reader(mystr, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    next(reader)  # skip header
    for line in reader:
        row = list(map(int, filter(None, line)))  # convert to integers
        if row[0] > 0:  # apply condition
            res.append(row)

print(res)

[[1, 66, 78, 9], [2, 50, 45, 4]]
```

Comment: OP is not asking to skip rows with zeros unless they are in the inital block.

Comment: Aside from that, this seems like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score -3):

```
lst = []
flag = 0 

with open('a.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            if float(line.split()[0].strip('.')) >0:
                flag = 1 
            if flag == 1:
                lst += [float(i.strip('.')) for i in line.split()]
        except: 
            pass
```

Comment: Passing on all errors for starters. Make sure to only pass ValueError.

Comment: Converting to float when you're dealing with integers

Comment: Stripping off decimal points for no reason. If you're using float type conversion, commit to it. Your code says .2 > 1 because you interpret it as 2.

Comment: Splitting the line twice and converting the first element twice.

Comment: Not using bool type for flag, which is also poorly named (though those are just nitpicks)

Comment: Turning the file into a 1D instead of a 2D list.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The data has been modified. The data contained float values before. (0.3. 0.8) Thanks for many of your suggestions.

Comment: I didn't check the modification. If the data did indeed contain floats, your answer would be even more wrong.